# Processing of cloud functions Firebase Realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I already asked this question to Firebase Support but they suggested to ask this question on community platforms. So I'm asking this question here in Stack Overflow.

1. Suppose a user creates new data in Firebase realtime database node.
2. This will trigger the onCreate cloud function, if added on that node.
3. In that cloud function, we are processing the added data such as updating the data by adding a new child by translating the particular child into a particular language.
4. While the onCreate cloud function is processing, suppose the user deletes the added data.
5. At this time, data is deleted but the onCreate cloud function is still processing and as a result, we will have a single child at that firebase path which contains the language translated data. This data is useless as it is already deleted by the user.

The questions are:

1. How can we solve this issue?
2. What is the better approach to solving these kinds of issues?

Comment: What should happen if a user deletes a parent that HAS the child? Do you delete the child as well? How do you delete it? Second question: can you have parents without children in your app?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec user will add the data to the list. For e.g: notes. So parent will be the notes which will have multiple notes

Comment: Actually, with the above questions, I wanted to check if you could not have a security rule that check if there is a child before deleting. I understand that this is not a possible approach, as there can be some parents without child. Other question: Do you confirm that you use the Realtime Database and not Firestore?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Yes, I use Realtime database.

Comment: There are dozens of approaches so I don't think a specific answer is possible. You could simply disallow a delete until the translation is complete. OR do a 'soft delete' where the user sees it deleted but it's not actually deleted until the translation completed. You could also invoke cloud functions that scrub your data and remove orphaned children on a regular basis (there are examples of that in the documentation).

Comment: @Jay app has offline capabilities.

Comment: My comments apply to both offline as well as online. You question states *This will trigger the onCreate cloud function* which means that if the app is offline, it will not do that action so maybe your can clarify the question?